# Determine the length (in milliseconds) of an mp3 file in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, mp3, taglib-sharp

Is there a way to get the time length of an mp3 in VB.net? I have TagLib, but it doesn't seem to have any functionality for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the TagLib.File.Properties.Duration, which returns a TimeSpan object.  From there you can use TotalSeconds to get the length of the mp3 in seconds.

Comment: And also TotalMilliseconds for milliseconds. :)

Answer (score 0):

add this to timer of track bar and dont forgot to add label in

```html
 Label4.Text = AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentItem.durationString
```

player